# Finding the maximum value of a function on an ellipse

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers such that $x^2 + 9 y^2-4 x+6 y+4=0$. Find the maximum value of $\displaystyle \frac{4x-9y}{2}$.

My solution: the given function represents an ellipse. Rewriting it, we get $\displaystyle (x-2)^2 + 9(y+\frac{1}{3})^2=1$. To find the maximum of $\displaystyle \frac{4x-9y}{2}$, $x$ should be at its maximum and $y$ at its minimum. Solving the equations, I get that $x = 3$ and $\displaystyle y = -\frac{2}{3}$, but the answer i get is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The point $(4, -\frac 2 3)$ is not on the ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is yet another way to approach the problem, which fits somewhere between the methods described by **Fly By Night** and **mathlove** .

The expression we seek to maximize can be treated as a function of two variables  $ \ z \ = \ f(x,y) \ = \ 2x \ - \ \frac{9}{2}y \ $ , which will produce as its level curves a family of parallel lines  $  2x \ - \ \frac{9}{2}y \ = \ c \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ \frac{4}{9}x \ - \ \frac{2}{9}c \ \ , $ as **mathlove** describes.  Thus, the value of  $ \ c \ $ corresponds to a change in the  $ \ y-$intercept of the line; there is a minimal value of  $ \ c \ $ for a line which is just tangent to the ellipse and a maximum value of  $ \ c \ $ for a line tangent elsewhere (we will discuss those tangent points shortly).

Looking at this in three dimensions, the equation $ \ x^2 - 4x + 9y^2 + 6y + 4 \ = \ 0 \ $ represents an elliptic cylinder, the cross-section of which is everywhere the same as the ellipse in the $ \ xy-$plane.  The function  $ \ z \ =  \ 2x \ - \ \frac{9}{2}y \ $ represents a plane slicing obliquely through this cylinder.  The problem at hand asks for the maximum "height" $ \ z \ $ above the   $ \ xy-$plane at which there is an intersection point between the cylinder and the plane.

[image]

Returning to the problem in two dimensions, we see then that we are seeking the point(s) at which the lines  $ \ y \ = \ \frac{4}{9}x \ - \ \frac{2}{9}c \  $ are tangent to the ellipse, which requires us to find the locations on the ellipse which match the slope of the lines.  (It will quickly be evident that there is no point in the interior of the ellipse that maximizes or minimizes $ \ c \  $ . )  By using implicit differentiation, we can find the slope of the tangent line to a point on the ellipse to be

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \ [ x^2 - 4x + 9y^2 + 6y + 4 ] \ = \ \frac{d}{dx} \ [ 0 ] \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ 2x - 4 + 18yy' + 6y'  \ = \  0  $$

$$ \Rightarrow  \ y'  \ = \  \frac{4 - 2x}{18y + 6} \ = \  \frac{2 - x}{3 \ (3y + 1)} \ . $$

It is this slope that we wish to set equal to the slope of the level curve lines:

$$   \frac{2 - x}{3 \ (3y + 1)} \ = \ \frac{4}{9} \ \Rightarrow \ 3 ( 2 - x ) \ = \ 4 ( 3y + 1 ) \ \Rightarrow \ y \ = \ \frac{1}{6} \ - \ \frac{1}{4}x \ . $$

The significance of this new linear equation is that the tangent points we are looking for lie on this line; what is also of interest is that we can write the equation as

$$  y \ - \ \frac{1}{6} \  + \ \frac{1}{2} \ = \  - \frac{1}{4} x \  + \ \frac{1}{2} \ \Rightarrow \ y \  +  \frac{1}{3} \ = \  - \frac{1}{4} ( x - 2 ) \  ; $$

this means that the tangent points lie at opposite ends of a line segment passing through the center of the ellipse, as found from the equation in standard form which **user117638** noted.  (We see this sort of result in similar problems for locating the extrema of linear functions on curves with four-fold symmetry.)  The matching of slopes of the tangent lines to the local slope of the ellipse is the essence of the Lagrange-multiplier method **Fly By Night** describes (what we are "really" doing is matching the gradient of the linear function to the local normal lines to points on the ellipse).

[image]

Now substituting  $ \ y \ = \ \frac{1}{6}  -  \frac{1}{4}x \ $ into the equation of the ellipse, $ \ (x - 2)^2 \ + \ 9(y+\frac{1}{3})^2 \ = \ 1 \ $ leads to the quadratic equation $ \ \frac{25}{16}x^2 \ - \ \frac{25}{4}x \ + \ \frac{21}{4} \ = \ 0 \  . $  Solving the two equations simultaneously leads to the coordinate pairs $ \ ( \frac{14}{5} \ , \ - \frac{8}{15}) \ \ \text{and} \ \ ( \frac{6}{5} \ , \ - \frac{2}{15}) \ . $  Inserting these now into the tangent line equation $ \ y \ = \ \frac{4}{9}x \ - \ \frac{2}{9}c \  $ gives us the two parallel lines

$$  y \ = \ \frac{4}{9}x \ - \ \frac{16}{9} \ \Rightarrow \ c = 8 $$

and

$$   y \ = \ \frac{4}{9}x \ - \ \frac{6}{9} \ \Rightarrow \ c = 3 \ \ , $$

thereby presenting us with the maximal and minimal values of the linear function on the ellipse, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

HINT : Letting $k=\frac{4x-9y}{2}$, this represents a line $y=\frac{4}{9}x-\frac{2}{9}k.$

Then, find the max $k$ such that the line is tangent to the ellipse.

You can set $y=\frac{4}{9}x-\frac{2}{9}k$ in the equation of the ellipse, then you'll get an equation of $x$. Then, find the condition that the equation has only one real solution. This gives you two $ks$. Then, the bigger $k$ is what you want.

Comment: can you please explain why is it neccessary for line to be tangent..

Comment: OK. Imagine the graph. There is a fixed ellipse. And note that the slope of the line is a constant. This means you can move the line with that the slope is a constant. So, you'll know there are two lines such that they are tangent to the ellipse. And what you want is the max of $k$. This means you want to know the minimum intercept of the line.

Comment: (part 2) The main reason why it is neccessary for line to be tangent is again that you need to find the max $k$. The line and the ellipse has to share at least one point, right? And $k$ has to be max. So, the line has to be tangent.

Comment: (Another explanation) Imagine that you move the line. Each intersection point $(x,y)$ of the line and the ellipse gives a value of $k$, right? To find the max $k$, $-2k/9$ has to be the min. The slope is a constant, so the line has to be tangent to the ellipse.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic application of the so-called [Lagrange Multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). We want to maximise the value of $2x-\tfrac{9}{2}y$ subject to the constraint $x^2 + 9 y^2-4 x+6 y+4=0$. We define

$$\Lambda(x,y,\lambda) = \left(2x-\tfrac{9}{2}y\right)+\lambda\left(x^2 + 9 y^2-4 x+6 y+4\right)$$

The point(s) you are looking for come from solving $\Lambda_x=\Lambda_y=\Lambda_{\lambda}=0$.

Calculating the three partial derivatives gives:
$$(x,y,\lambda) = \left(\frac{6}{5},-\frac{2}{15},\frac{5}{4}\right) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \left(\frac{14}{5},-\frac{8}{15},-\frac{5}{4}\right)$$

The values $(x,y)=(6/5,-2/15)$ correspond to a *minimum*, where $2x-\tfrac{9}{2}y=3$.

The values $(x,y)=(14/5,-8/15)$ correspond to a *maximum*, where $2x-\tfrac{9}{2}y=8$.

Answer (score 2):

Using parametric form, $\displaystyle x-2=\cos\phi,3\left(y+\frac13\right)=\sin\phi$

$\displaystyle\implies x=2+\cos\phi, 3y=\sin\phi-1 $

$\displaystyle\implies\frac{4x-9y}2=\frac{4(2+\cos\phi)-3(\sin\phi-1)}2=\frac{11+4\cos\phi-3\sin\phi}2$

Can you prove $$-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le a\cos \theta+b\sin\theta\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}?$$

Comment: yes i do know he last equation you wrote

Comment: @user117638, so you are done, right?

Comment: yes thankyou,..