# points on the curve $x^2+2y^2=6$ whose distance from the line $x+y-7=0$ is minimum

Tags: inequality

> Find point on the curve $x^2+2y^2=6$ whose distance from the line $x+y-7=0$ is, minimum

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $(x,y)$ be any point on the curve $x^2+2y^2=6\;,$ Then we have to

minimize $\displaystyle \left|\frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}\right|$

Using $\bf{Cauchy\; Schwarz}$ Inequality

$$\left[x^2+\left(\sqrt{2}y\right)^2\right]\cdot \left[1^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\right]\geq (x+y)^2$$

So $$6\times \frac{3}{2}\geq (x+y)^2\Rightarrow (x+y)^2\leq 3^2\Rightarrow-3 \leq  (x+y)\leq 3$$

So We get $$\frac{-3-7}{\sqrt{2}}\leq \frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}\leq \frac{3-7}{\sqrt{2}}\Rightarrow -5\sqrt{2}\leq \frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}\leq -2\sqrt{2}$$

and equality hold when $\displaystyle \frac{x}{1} = \frac{2y}{1}$

Now i did not understand how can i calculate $\displaystyle \min \left|\frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}\right|,$ Help me thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618106/finding-the-maximum-value-of-a-function-on-an-ellipse

Comment: You already solved the problem but the last step, which is $5\sqrt{2}\geq\left| \frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}\right|\geq 2\sqrt{2}$, and in the latter inequality the equality is attained. So the required minimum is $2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t = x+y$, you've shown $-3 \le t \le 3$, thus the function $f(t) =\dfrac{ (t-7)^2}{2}$ has a graph a parabola with the axis of symmetry at $x = 7$, and it is decreasing on $[-3,3]$, thus the min is $f(3) = 8$. Thus the min distance is $2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG any point on $x^2+2y^2=6$ can be P$(\sqrt6\cos t,\sqrt3\sin t)$

Now the distance of $P$ from $x+y-7=0$ is $$\dfrac{|\sqrt6\cos t+\sqrt3\sin t-7|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}=\dfrac{\left|3\cos\left(t-\arccos\dfrac{\sqrt6}3\right)-7\right|}{\sqrt2}$$

Now $-1\le\cos\left(t-\arccos\dfrac{\sqrt6}3\right)\le1$

$\implies-3-7\le\sqrt6\cos t+\sqrt3\sin t-7\le3-7$

$\implies4\le|\sqrt6\cos t+\sqrt3\sin t-7|\le10$

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Alex Ravsky, you can have $2\sqrt{2}\leq |\frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}|\leq 5\sqrt{2}$ from $-5\sqrt{2}\leq \frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}\leq -2\sqrt{2}$ which you have correctly got. As you wrote, we have $x=2y$, so the answer is $(x,y)=(2,1)$.

---

In the following, I'm going to show a solution which does not use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

As you wrote, we want to find $(x,y)$ such that $\bigg|\dfrac{x+y-7}{\sqrt 2}\bigg|$ is minimized under the condition that $x^2+2y^2=6$.

So, we want to find $(x,y)$ such that $|x+y-7|$ is minimized under the condition that $x^2+2y^2=6$.

Let $k:=x+y-7$.

Let us first find the condition on $k$ that there is at least one $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2+2y^2=6$ and $k=x+y-7$.

Eliminating $y$ from $x^2+2y^2=6$ and $y=-x+k+7$ gives
$$x^2+2(-x+k+7)^2=6$$
i.e.
$$3x^2+(-4k-28)x+2 k^2 + 28 k + 92=0\tag2$$

In order for real $x$ to exist, we have
$$(-4k-28)^2-4\cdot 3(2 k^2 + 28 k + 92)\ge 0$$
i.e.
$$-10\le k\le -4$$

Now, we can say that $|k|$ is minimized when $k=-4$.

Solving $(2)$ for $k=-4$ gives $x=2$, and from $y=-x+k+7$, we get $y=1$.

Therefore, the answer is $\color{red}{(x,y)=(2,1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some other ways which are more common...

1. The tangent line of the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=6$ at the closest point to the given line $x+y-7=0$ is parallel to the given line: $-\frac{x}{2y}=-1$ and hence $x=2y$.
2. Lagrange's multiplier: $2x=\frac{x+y-7}{|x+y-7|}\lambda$ and $4y=\frac{x+y-7}{|x+y-7|}\lambda$ gives $\frac{x}{2y}=1$ by dividing equations.
3. Pulling $y$ (Alternatively pulling $x$) : $|\sqrt{6-2y^2}+y-7|'=0$ gives $y=\pm 1$.
4. Distance function:
   $$ d(x,x')=(x-x')^2+\left(\sqrt{\frac{6-x^2}{2}}+7-x'\right)^2.$$
   $d_{x}=d_{x'}=0$ gives $x=\pm 2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \min{\left\{\left|\frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}\right|:\forall (x,y)\in \left\{x^2+2y^2=6\right\}\right\}}$

$\displaystyle L=\frac{x+y-7}{\sqrt{2}}+\lambda (x^2+2y^2-6)$

$\displaystyle L_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+2\lambda x=0$

$\displaystyle L_y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+4\lambda y=0$

$\displaystyle L_\lambda=x^2+2y^2=6$

Solve this system of equations and we have $\displaystyle x=2,y=1,\lambda =-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}$.

Therefore, at point $(2,1)$ the distance between two functions is the minimum.